# Node.js external file for routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Hi why is it that when I use external file for routes it doesn't send anything in the browser? It just keeps on loading and nothing happens.

server.js

```
var myurl = express.Router();
require('./app/routes/myurl.js')(myurl);
app.use('/', myurl);
```

app/routes/myurl.js

```
module.exports = function (router) {

    router.get('/', function(req,res){
        res.send('test only');
    });

}
```

Comment: I believe in your `myurl.js` you need to require express. See the [guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
```

in your server.js / app.js

then index.js that is in /routes/ directory :

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
 // handle your route here
});

module.exports = router;
```

so when you go to ..../index, you will get it from index route.
nodeJS + ExpressJs actually have a very useful boilerplate :

http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

You will see exactly how it works.

Comment: var express = require('express'); in app/server.js of course

Comment: i just need to add `router = express.Router()` after requiring express in my routes. Thanks btw.